# Prioritize write cache over read cache on Linux

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel

My pc (with 4 GB of RAM) is running several IO bound applications, and I want to avoid as many writes as possible on my SSD.

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` file I have set:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 75
vm.dirty_ratio = 90
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 360000
vm.swappiness = 0
```

And in `/etc/fstab` I added the `commit=3600` parameter.

According to `free` command, my pc usually stays on with 1 GB of RAM used by applications and about 2500 of available ram. So with my settings I should be able to write at least about 1500-2000 MB of data without writing actually on the disk.

I have done some tests with moderate writes (300MB - 1000MB) and with `free` and `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Dirty` commands I noticed that often a few time later these writes (far less that `dirty_expire_centisecs` time), the dirty bytes go down to a value next to 0.

I suspect that the subsequent read operations fill the cache until the machine is near a OOM condition and is forced to flush dirty writes ignoring my `sysctl.conf` settings (correct me if my hypothesis is wrong).

So the question is: is it possible disabling only read caching (AFAIK not possible), or at least change pagecache replace policy, giving more priority to write cache, so that read cache can not force a writes flushing (maybe tweaking kernel source code...)? I know that I can solve easily this problem using tmpfs or union-fs like AUFS or OverlayFS, but for many reason I would like to avoid them.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand my question. Thank you.